# AJAX login without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication, reloading

I was logging into my iCloud account and I was wondering how it was possible for them to log me in without reloading the page. As I know it is not possible for jQuery to execute any PHP scripts, nor possible to create a session after the page has been loaded. I believe that it may be using some cookies or something, but still I don't understand how they make php get these cookies without reloading the page after login.

Comment: All of those things are possible by simply sending an ajax request.

Comment: Okay.. i know that ajax can return data, but how do I separate those data? I mean.. I can check `if(data == '1') { success: function()` but  how would I separate name, email, username etc.?

Comment: Send it back as json data using `echo json_encode(your array of data here)` and set the datatype in `$.ajax` to `"json"`, you can then access that data as the first param in the success callback `success: function(data) { console.log(data) }`

Comment: Just another question about stackoverflow.. How do I set your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: You can't, I would have to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send it back as json data using

```
echo json_encode(your array of data here)
```

and set the datatype in `$.ajax` to `"json"`, you can then access that data as the first param in the success callback

```
success: function(data) { 
     console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Its taken care by browser**.

Browser automatically sends all cookies specific to your application to the server and then server decides their validity. This information is passed in the header of the http request. So if cookie is valid server will recover your session information and hence will log you in.

Comment: This makes no sense ... the server doesn't validate a users 'state' ... html is stateless.

Comment: what makes you think so...and btw http is stateless and NOT html.

Comment: Correction accepted :: [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) However, browsers don't automatically 'add user authentication cookies' ... that functionality must be implemented by a developer